# efficiency of regular expression based replace

Tags: java, regex, performance

Which of the following would be more efficient and better to use?

```
value.replaceAll("['‘’`]","")

value.replaceAll("['‘’`]+","")
```

My guess would be that for strings that don't have the replaced chars, or at least don't have sequences of them the two are the same or the first is better being less complex.

but what if I am looking at strings that do have sub-sequences of the chars being replaced ?
will the second one be better ?

```
'abababababababab'.replaceAll("ab","")
```

v.s.

```
'abababababababab'.replaceAll("(ab)+","")
```

I am using Java if this matters for the sake of this Q.

Comment: Why not write a simple program to time how long each technique takes?

Comment: I don't think you will notice any speed execution difference unless you're planning feed it **really** big strings. So if you're not, you don't mind actually.

Comment: @David, because I assumed someone already has an answer.
m0skit0 you are no doubt right. Its just a matter of wanting to know.

Comment: It heavily depends on how `replaceAll()` is implemented internally, which could (and most likely will be) different depending on which JDK you're using and even its version.

Comment: @m0skit0 lets assume its built in the most efficient possible way...
I would still expect that the second one would be faster because it will not have to "context switch" between the replace loop and the regex internal loop... only way I can think of for the first to be faster is if the setup/compilation of the regex takes more time then   the said context switches..

Comment: The + case enables the best processing and is not really much more complicated (a loop so to say). So the internal (costly) `Pattern.compile` will not be that much larger. If the replaceAll happens more than once, use a global **Pattern**. That will save more time.

Comment: If efficiency is a concern, and when dealing with such a trivial pattern match, it is probably better to write bespoke code for the replacement. General code is almost always slower than code optimized for one particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per analysis I would say the first option is faster than the second. Although I must say that this difference is not easily measurable unless you have a huge string as input (or complex regex).

So lets call this regex1:

```
'abababababababab'.replaceAll("ab","")
```

And this regex2:

```
'abababababababab'.replaceAll("(ab)+","")
```

We know from [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) that the replaceAll will see [both the conditions as a regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and the try to replace the string following the regex engine.

We can see that regex1 have the char sequence only; while and the regex2 have a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), a char sequence and the a [quantifier metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) that must be interpreted accordingly (more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)). Therefore regex2 need more processing than regex1.

In general both options are really fast for most uses. You can have a more detailed view on the process by reading this article: [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

Still, using the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more complex regex is a faster option... (more info [here](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16822&tstart=0)).

Also an additional reading I recommend in this scenario is: [Optimizing Regular Expressions in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-optimizingregex.html)

Comment: You say "Therefore regex2 need more processing than regex1." o.k. that is obvious. but the result is that replaceAll will effectively do just a single replace of the entire string to an  empty string. whereas in the first case the match will occur multiple times and each will have to be replaced separately. does this not mean that (at least for long strings) regex2 would become more effective then regx1 ?

Comment: @epeleg true indeed, in that scenario the replacing will be repeated over and over for the regex1; what if we had a file with 1gb of "ababab..." regex1 would compile and match/replace 'ab' several times and regex2 will compile and at each 'ab' have a decision about whether replace or keep looking (state machine - more explanation on the article mentioned on the answer) based on the metacharacters. Imagine another scenario with 1gb txt file with 'abcabcabc...' and the same regex. Although, I personally feel that I would chose regex2 for being more robust with real data...